# android linearlayout and textview wrap_content cause cutting the last line of text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout which is simplified like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/very_long_text"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="cancel"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="yes"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The value of `@string/very_long_text` is:

```
a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see the text is cutted. I know I can change the `width` of `textview` to be `wrap_content` and then text will be completely displayed, but it changes width of layout to be full screen and it is not desired. What causes this problem? How I can solve the problem?

*Edit*

I use this as layout of Activity which must be look like to a dialog.

Comment: try using relative layout as parent layout.

Comment: Is this an alert dialog with custom view? If not, Is height of parent fixed?

Comment: what output are you expecting ??

Comment: @Ranjan I use this as layout of Activity which must be look like to a dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try with below

**Using ConstraintLayout**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnYes"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnYes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnYes"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="yes"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnCancel"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtMessage" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Is setting fixed width a bad practice?

Comment: I know that's why i already wrote if you are go with LinearLayout in my answer.
I already we have another solutions to get this using `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: @hasanghaforian : getting chance to check updated answer? Still have any issue let me know.

Comment: @hasanghaforian : have you check this?

Comment: Yes I checked that. Using `ConstraintLayout` is a good point. But we need to set margins fixed yet.

Comment: I set `width` of `TextView` like this: `android:layout_width="0dp"`. Now it produced my desired UI without needing to setting `margin` for parent. Please remove first part of your answer and change `width` to `0dp` in second part. So it will be clear for others.

Comment: @hasanghaforian:  Updated

Answer (score 1):

you can use `margins`  with `match_parent` property to `parent layout`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="cancel"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="yes"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Setting fixed margin, will cause small margin on tablets.

Comment: @hasanghaforian you can design separate design for tablets. Android gives you the option for this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="cancel"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="yes"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

set top linear layout as match parent textview as wrap conten as above

Comment: In this way `width` of layout will be full screen and it is not desired.

Comment: then how much width u want that width u need to set